# cannot find any .CSV files

Tags: excel, csv

I did search through many of the .csv realated topics that the search returned so I hope this is an appropriate new question...

I am trying to setup an excel spreadsheet using a .csv file as the data source, very simple but here's the issue;
I cannot find ANY .csv file I have saved after exporting it from the program in which I run my report from. I export and save the report, type my desired file name and am able to chose from tab or comma delimited files. I have saved to my desktop, documents folder, favorites, etc. When I search for the files in my computer or the import data window in Excel, they are nowhere to be found even when typing the exact file name in the search bar. If I go back to my report and re-export it, I can see the file already saved and will even prompt me if I attempt to save using the same name.

I have gone into folder settings and verified all hidden items are showing, I'm at a complete loss and have spent quite a fair amount of time browsing for a solution today.

Win 7 enterprise btw...not sure if that matters.

Thanks as always!

Comment: How does this relate to programming?

Comment: a Guess.. When you try to import a file, See if you can chose "All files" from the dropdown box just below the filename textbox

Comment: Yes all files selected, still not there, searched every folder as well.
@CharlieFish It doesn't **directly** I suppose, however if I were able to find any of these .csv files I would then be pulling them into excel and working on my VBA skills from there

Comment: What program are you using to export these files?

Comment: Also, @CharlieFish is right, this is more of a SuperUser question.

Comment: fair enough, took it to superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your folders are set to show file extensions.  Because a CSV file will have the same icon as any Excel document.  It will even launch Excel when you double click on it.
There is pretty much no way to tell them apart unless the extensions are turned on.  And by default they are off.

Comment: the file name **itself** is nowhere to be found, any of the .csv files I have saved for that matter.

Comment: If you are personally and physically exporting those files (Save As), then you must know where you are putting them.  If you are just exporting them and paying no attention to where they are going, then I suggest looking harder.  :)

Comment: I have attempted to save in multiple locations including the desktop, none of which files appear anywhere, and again, they do not even populate using search. I am not unaware of where I am saving the files, or the file extension, they are simply no where to be found. 

I have since brought this question to SuperUser as suggested.

**any mod feel free to remove**

Comment: You realize, the trouble here is that you are not specifying what app you are exporting from.  You are also not showing any code.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue with one of our database, I added the ".CSV" after file name. Try to see it its works.

Comment: tried this but the file still does not appear in any of the folders I saved it in.

Comment: post some screen shot while exporting to CSV